# Create a pull request in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pull-request

We have a git setup with pull requests. The PR are hooked into Jenkins, where the PR are tested before they are merged.

Jenkins runs through Pipeline through a set of stages. But I would like Jenkins to create an additional PR towards another branch if the building and testing is successful.

As an example

> A -> PR (manually created) -> B -> PR (Jenkins) -> C

I have installed [hub](https://hub.github.com/), and I try running

> hub pull-request -b target_branch

But I encounter a lot of issues:

- Delocated HEAD (not in a branch)
- "base" value is not valid (hub specific, does not find target branch)
- origin/target_branch does not exist
- and so on

Below is the snippet where I try to create a pull request in the Jenkinsfile. While not a lot, it tries to checkout the origin branch to a local branch, and then create a PR towards the origin/demo (which exist)

```
    stage('Pull request') {
        sh 'git checkout -b ' + env.BRANCH_NAME + ' origin/' + env.BRANCH_NAME
        sh 'hub pull-request -b origin/demo'
    }
```

Have anyone implemented this? Is something like this what was accomplished, or did you go another route? Or is this not possible (in a manageable way)?

**EDIT**

In response to the comment I would like to clarify my issue in such a clear way possible.

- How would I manage the issue of detached HEAD when running **checkout scm**? Is it the way presented in the code snippet above?
- Why does

  > hub pull-request -b origin/demo

  result in "base" value is not valid (hub does not find **origin/demo** branch)
- The same goes for git. How do I make the workspaces aware of other remote branches?

Comment: What is the error? + Can't you use multi branch pipelines which you can run for each PR?

Comment: We have epic-branches that are forked for each new feature, and then merged back with PR. But when a PR successfully is merged back to an epic-branch, we would like to make a new PR from the merged epic-branch to a staging-branch.

Comment: @DavidGustavsson Is there an accepted answer for this query, I was about to create a question along the same line, saw this post and was looking for a recommendation

Comment: No sorry. We changed to gitlab, and update our workflow so that we did not need to publish new PR's when merging.